# Load HTML script and video play in WebBrowser Control in WP7

Tags: c#, javascript, html, windows-phone-7, browser

I am facing problem in loading the script and auto playing the videos from youtube, vimeo etc. I am not able to load the content from the below script in webbrowser control.
Below is my C# code.

```
string html = "<!doctype html><html><head><title></title></head><body><div id='_cvp_11293'><span></span></div><script type='text/javascript'>(function(){var a;a=new XMLHttpRequest;a.onreadystatechange=function(){rs=a.readyState;if(4==rs&&200==a.status){var c=JSON.parse(a.responseText),b;for(b in c.payload)if(c.payload.hasOwnProperty(b)){var d=c.payload[b];document.getElementById('_cvp_'+b).innerHTML=d.view}}};a.open('GET','http://media.yesheis.com/multi_player?ids=11293&w=300&h=225&autoplay=1&provider=youtube',!0);a.send()})(window);</script></body></html>";
web.IsScriptEnabled = true;
web.NavigateToString(html);
```

XAML :

```
<phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsScriptEnabled="True" Margin="36,44,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="web" Width="350" Height="500" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your C# code is fine.

However, your HTML code is broken.
Just save it to the HTML page on some web server (your local IIS will do great), and navigate there with your windows phone's built-in Internet Explorer - you'll only see a white screen.

In your HTML there's a JavaScript that does a cross-domain XMLHttpRequest. That's why the line `a.open('GET', 'http://media.yesheis.com/multi_player?ids=11293&w=300&h=225&autoplay=1&provider=youtube', !0);` throws an access denied exception.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: You could perform that HTTP GET request from the C# code instead of JavaScript. Then parse JSON, only then `wb.NavigateToString( "<!doctype html><html><body>" + view + "</body></html>" )`, where view is the "view" field from the JSON response.